# Sort a list created by matches in dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary

i am a newbie to python. I have a dictionary and a string of keys. I must check if the keys are present in the dictionary and return the list of matches. If two or more keys match the same then that value should come first.

So far, i got until printing the matches. I am looking for ideas on how to proceed with the sort.

My code is as follows:

```
def lookupKeyword(string):

    try:
        dict1 = {'title1': 'title1 an title2', 'title2': 'title7 an title2', 'title3': 'title3 an title2', 'title4': 'title4 an title2', 'title5': 'title5 an title2', 'title6': 'title6 an title2', 'title7': 'title7 an title2'}
        string1 = string.split(",")
        i = 0

        bookList = []
        while(i<len(string1)):
          try:
           if string1[i] in dict1:
            #number_of_matches = 0
            temp = string1[i]
            temp1 = dict1[temp]
            bookList.insert(i,temp1)
            #number_of_matches += 1
          except NoResultsError:
            print "NoResultsError-There are no matches for the given query"
          i += 1
        for x in bookList:
          print x

      except:
        print "There seems to be some error in getting the required details2"

lookupKeyword("title3,title2,title1")
```

now the bookList looks like

1. title3 an title2
2. title7 an title2
3. title1 an title2

but since there is a match for title1 and title2 in the dictionary i want "**title1 an title2**" to come first i.e

1. title1 an title2
2. title3 an title2
3. title7 an title2

Comment: Dont understand. You want to sort bookList? Then use `sorted(bookList)`

Comment: Can you clarify what your sorting criteria is? I'm not sure what you mean by "if two or more keys match the same then that value should come first".

Comment: Hey guys, added a few clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is to calculate totals and sort on them, then to filter 0's:

```
def lookupKeyword(dict1, string):
        string1 = string.split(",")
        match = [ v for k, v in dict1.items() if k in string1 ]
        r = sorted((sum(s in v for s in string1), v) for v in match)
        return [ v[1] for v in reversed(r) if v[0] ]

dict1 = {'title1': 'title1 an title2', 'title2': 'title7 an title2', 
        'title3': 'title3 an title2', 'title4': 'title4 an title2', 
        'title5': 'title5 an title2', 'title6': 'title6 an title2', 
        'title7': 'title7 an title2'}

r = lookupKeyword(dict1, "title3,title2,title1")
for t in r: print t
```

This gives:

```
title3 an title2
title1 an title2
title7 an title2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can help you:

```
def lookup_keyword(string):

    dict1 = {'title1': 'title1 an title2', 'title2': 'title7 an title2',
             'title3': 'title3 an title2', 'title4': 'title4 an title2',
             'title5': 'title5 an title2', 'title6': 'title6 an title2',
             'title7': 'title7 an title2'}

    string_list = string.split(',')

    r = [v for k, v in dict1.items() if k in string_list]

    if not r:
        print("There seems to be some error in getting the required details2")

    else:
        r.sort()

        for x in r:
            print(x)
```

Test:

```
>>> lookup_keyword("title3,title2,title1")
title1 an title2
title3 an title2
title7 an title2
```

Comment: Yeah ! This works. Can you just explain the code for variable 'r'?

Comment: r is a result of lookup